# Re-connecting to remotely run kernel with jupyter lab

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a remote server with jupyter lab and has one job running. However, the connection was dropped and now I'm trying to re-connect to the same running kernel. I honestly read through many examples and jupyter docs, but I couldn't find a solution. My previous run was outputting intermediate results and I am wondering whether I can re-connect back to the running kernel and continue see the output?

I normally connect via ssh:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8080 usere@123.45.678.9
```

...

then I run

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080
```

and in the browser on my local machine I simply open 'locahost:8000' and it works nicely.

I tried to repeat those steps but I can't re-connect to existing running kernel and continue see the output.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: When you try to reconnect what are you getting exactly? Page not found?

Comment: No, I simply see the last moment (output) I saw just before the connection dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly, I understand your problem. So you are not let server keep running. Instead, you manually launch it everytime.

Basically the idea is that you need to make it keep running. Somehow like `nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080 &` or use `systemd`. So that when you lose connection, the jupyter server is still running.

Then you can just reconnect to server by `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8080 usere@123.45.678.9`. And open `locahost:8000`. Finally you will see that everything is just the same as you left.

Comment: Your suggestion to keep it running is generally a good idea. However, it didn't solve the stated problem for me